# How to plot variance of a changing array using matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

I am trying to plot the variance of a difference array vs the constant. By equation this is what I am trying to plot

`diff[n] = arrInput[n] - k*arrInput[n-1]`

I need to plot variance of diff[n] vs k. I am new to matplotlib and signal processing in general, so I am very much stuck with this.

What I did was to create and array like this:

```
diff = []
for i in range(1, len(arrInput)): 
    diff.append(arrInput[i] - arrInput[i-1])
```

But I am not able to understand how can I multiply the `i-1` term with a changing constant and plot it.

I did try using `np.linspace(0,1)` to create equally spaced terms for k like this:

```
k = np.linspace(0,1)
```

But when I try to plot above like this: `plt.plot(np.var(dd),k)` I get the following error

> x and y must have same first dimension, but "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape

I would appreciate any help.

**Edit**
To clarify and put in short:
I want to plot the graph of variance of (`diff[n]`) vs `k` from the equation `diff[n] = arrInput[n] - k*arrInput[n-1]`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiply the `i-1` term with a *changing constant* and plot it."?

Comment: @jaaq I mean I want to plot `diff[n]` vs `k` on a graph from the equation `diff[n] = arrInput[n] - k*arrInput[n-1]`, where k is to vary between 0 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each value of `k` you want to plot the variance of `diff(k;n)` with respect to its `n` dimension, with `k` being essentially a constant parameter for the duration of the variance calculation. For this you just have to compute the diff and its variance for each value of `k`, and gather them in a list or array for plotting. You can do this manually using a loop, but you can also use broadcasting operations to easily get a 2d array I above called "`diff(k;n)`" and compute the variance for each value of `k` in a single call to `var()`.

Here are both approaches:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dummy data: random arrays for the diff
N = 100  # size of the array for a given k
Nk = 51  # number of "k" values later
arr = np.random.random(N)  # shape (N,)

# pedestrian method: for each k compute the diff and its variance
def weighted_diff_var(arr, k):
    """Compute variance of diff such that diff[n] = arr[n] - k*arr[n-1] for a fixed k"""
    diff = arr[1:] - k * arr[:-1]  # diff[0] = arr[1] - k*arr[0], diff[1] = arr[2] - k*arr[1], etc.
    var = diff.var()
    return var

# advanced method: compute a 2d array of shape (Nk, N) and compute the variance in one go
def weighted_diff_var_vectorized(arr, Nk=Nk):
    """Compute variance in one go for each k using broadcasting and vectorization"""
    all_ks = np.linspace(0, 1, Nk)[:,None]  # shape (Nk, 1) for broadcasting
    all_diffs = arr[1:] - all_ks * arr[:-1]  # broadcast to shape (Nk, N)
    vars_vectorized = all_diffs.var(axis=1)
    return vars_vectorized

all_ks = np.linspace(0, 1, Nk)  # shape (Nk,)
vars_loopy = [weighted_diff_var(arr, k) for k in all_ks]  # or np.array(...); note the loop
vars_vectorized = weighted_diff_var_vectorized(arr)  # shape (Nk,) directly

plt.plot(all_ks, vars_loopy, 'o-', label='loopy')
plt.plot(all_ks, vars_vectorized, 'x-', label='vectorized')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('var(diff)')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

The first function `weighted_diff_var` takes a single `k` value as input and computes the `diff` then the variance according to your prescription. Of course we need to loop over each `k` value and call this function, which is what this list comprehension does:

```
vars_loopy = [weighted_diff_var(arr, k) for k in all_ks]
```

Alternatively, we can create a 2d array with dimensions for "`k`" and "`n`", so to speak, and compute its variance along a given axis (the axis for "`n`"). This is what happens in `weighted_diff_var_vectorized`, where a single call will give us an array containing the variance for each `k`. Then we plot the two results together to prove that they do the same thing:
[image: plot of both methods: perfect overlap]

As you can see both methods give the exact same results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell pyplot what your x-axis looks like first and then add the y coordinates afterwards.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k_is_constant = True

def calculate_k(i):
    if k_is_constant:
        return 0.1  # this can be any number you like. Maybe check out argparse
    else:
        #provide a function to calculate k from i. here i will alternate between 0 and 1
        return i%2

arrIn = list(range(50))

y = list()

for i in range(1, len(arrIn)):
    y.append(arrIn[i] - calculate_k(i)*arrIn[i-1])

x = list(range(len(y)))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

If you want k to change for different executions of your programs, maybe [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/argparse.html) is what you need.

Comment: what if I don't want to put k as constant and plot the graph of this vs k where k is varying between say 0 to 1?

Comment: edited it. Just do `(i % 2)` or if you want to flip it `((i+1)%2)`

Comment: I meant that k is any number between 0 and 1 and the graph plots different values of diff[I] for different k

Comment: okay did another edit. if this still doesn't suit you, you'll have to be **way more precise** in what you're trying to do and what is and what isn't working. Maybe provide a link to a paper or write down a mathematical correlation or something.